# Can indexer in azure search use any other character instead of , as a delimiter to break words and put in a collection type azure search index field?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, indexer

I am running indexer to seed data to azure search index and the data source for the indexer is a sql view. Azure uses Comma delimiter to split and put data into collection type field. Is there any other delimiter that I can configure to use instead of comma?

Let's say I have this list of strings that I want to be part of index collection type field 1.)"item1, test" 2.)"item2, test". From my sql view I return this data as item1~ test,item2~ test. I am replacing my , in each word with ~ because azure treats , as a delimiter for its collection type field and I don't want azure breaking my string in the wrong place. Now azure saves this data as "item1~ test", "item2~ test". When I am returning search results I replace ~ back with ,

The problem I am facing with this technique is that when a user searches for item1 it is treating item1~ as partial match because of ~ and weighing it's score down. In the background that's just item1 to me and I want that be treated as full match.

So I was wondering if I can use any other delimiter instead of , so that I don't have to replace it with special characters and replace it back in my search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to change the output of the view to return the SQL string to be a string that is a JSON array of strings?

A SQL string can be used to populate a Collection(Edm.String) field if the string represents a JSON array of strings: ["red", "white", "blue"]
[SQL data mapping][1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers#mapping-between-sql-and-azure-search-data-types)

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked except for records of these types ["red "The Red" red it is", "white", "blue"]. Do you have any suggestions on how to handle this data?

Comment: All SQL strings need to be wellformed JSON for this to work.  Looking at the example, it doesn't appear to be wellformed so you would need to do some sort of additional transformation on the data before our built in mappings can be used.